# Android calendar set wrong date after event update

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I need to update the description of a calendar event.

This is my code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "my description");
Uri updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventId);
int update = mContentResolver.update(updateUri, values, null, null);
```

I write in logcat before and after I call my code:

Before (ok for me):

> DTSTART = 07/02/2015 00:00:00
>   DTEND = 07/02/2015 23:59:59

After (wrong):

> DTSTART = 06/02/2015 01:00:00
>   DTEND = 07/02/2015 01:00:00

so my event is moved to the previous day.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by before and after  i call my code? And post the code how you set the date

Answer (score 1):

Pass the DTSTART and DTEND along with the description you want to update, that will solve the issue, but remember in case of recurring event DTEND is not allowed so add a checking for that

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "my description");
values.put(Events.DTSTART,"your event start time in milliseconds here");
values.put(Events.DTEND,"your event end  time in milliseconds here");
Uri updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventId);
int update = mContentResolver.update(updateUri, values, null, null);
```

Hopes this will helps :)